# A problem in probability theory

Tags: probability, self-study

I was trying to solve a problem and I got stuck at the penultimate step (I think).

I could show that Var(X) = Var(Y) = Cov(X,Y), where X and Y are random variables with finite means and variances.

Based on above statement, can I say that X and Y are the same? or P(X=Y) = 1?

Comment: **Hint**: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: From regression theory point of view and Var(Y) = Cov(X,Y), I can say that X explains all the variance in Y and therefore is essentially the same (upto a multiplicative constant i.e. Y = cX). But how do I show that c=1? I can't see how I can apply Cauchy-Schwarz here..

Comment: Additional hint (following @cardinal): the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is easily proven by observing that $0 \le \text{Var}(X-Y)$ and expanding the right hand side.  What can you conclude about a random variable whose variance is zero?

Comment: This additional hint helped me solve this problem. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: If Y =cX then Var(Y)=c$^2$Var(X) implying c$^2$=1. So c=1 or -1.  But if Y=-X, Cov(X,Y)=Cov(X,-X)=-Var(X).  Therefore Y=X.

Comment: @Michael, you seem to be showing the converse. A minor detail, but important in light of the question, is that even when arguing in the direction you have, the conclusion $X=Y$ is "only" true *almost surely*.

Comment: @cardinal The problem is not stated in a way that you can which result is the answer to the problem and which is the converse.  But it does appear to me that the OP wante to show that P(X=Y)=1. I am proving this by contradiction.  I think it is fairly obvious that nothing changes with regard to all the expectations when X and Y differ on a set of measure 0. So yes I am show X=Y a.s. and hence P{X=Y]=1.

Comment: In your comment, you've assumed *a priori* that $Y = c X$, for some $c$, whereas this is (effectively) what the OP wants to *show* (with $c = 1$). :-)

Comment: Actually I just picked up the argument where steadyfish left off. He said that Var(Y)=Cov(X,Y) implies that Y = cX (a.s.) and asked "But how do I show that c=1?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need the following simple result.

**Lemma.** If $\mathrm{Var}[Z]=0$, then $Z=\mathrm{E}[Z]$, almost surely.

**Proof (check cardinal's comment for a contrapositive argument).** It is easy to check that
$$
  \left\{ Z = \mathrm{E}[Z] \right\} = \bigcap_{n\geq 1} \left\{ |Z - \mathrm{E}[Z]| < \frac{1}{n} \right\} \, .
$$
By Tchebyshev's inequality, we have
$$
  P \left\{ |Z - \mathrm{E}[Z]| \geq \frac{1}{n} \right\} \leq n^2 \mathrm{Var}[Z] = 0 \, ,
$$
for every $n\geq 1$. Hence, using De Morgan's identity and the subadditivity of $P$, we have
$$
  P\left\{ Z = \mathrm{E}[Z] \right\} = 1 - P\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1} \left\{ |Z - \mathrm{E}[Z]| \geq \frac{1}{n} \right\}\right) \geq 1 - \sum_{n\geq 1} P\left\{ |Z - \mathrm{E}[Z]| \geq \frac{1}{n} \right\} = 1 \, ,
$$
as desired.

Using the hints given by cardinal and whuber, you have what you need.

**Proposition.** If $X$ and $Y$ are integrable random variables such that $$\mathrm{Var}[X] = \mathrm{Var}[Y]=\mathrm{Cov}[X,Y] \, ,$$ then $X=Y+c$, almost surely, where the constant $c=\mathrm{E}[X]-\mathrm{E}[Y]$.

**Proof.** Defining $Z=X-Y$, the formula for the variance of the difference of two random variables gives
$$
\mathrm{Var}[Z]=\mathrm{Var}[X]+\mathrm{Var}[Y]-2\,\mathrm{Cov}[X,Y] = 2\,\mathrm{Cov}[X,Y] -2\,\mathrm{Cov}[X,Y] = 0 \, .
$$
The Lemma yields the desired result, since $\mathrm{E}[Z]=\mathrm{E}[X-Y]=\mathrm{E}[X]-\mathrm{E}[Y]$.

Comment: (+1) You are really cleaning up the backlog on these problems! :-) Good work. An alternative argument for the first part: For $W \geq 0$, $\mathbb E W = 0$ implies $W = 0$ a.s. To see this, note that if $W \neq 0$ almost surely then there is a $\delta > 0$ and a set $A$ of positive measure such that $W > \delta$ on $A$. Hence $\mathbb E W > \delta \mathbb P(A) > 0$. Now, take $W = (Z - \mathbb E Z)^2$ to get the result for the variance.

Comment: Nice contrapositive proof!